# Trouble comparing numeric variables in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I am attempting to solve one of those grid logic problems with swi-prolog. I am able to program most of the rules, however, this rule is tripping me up:

> The ambassador with the 3 day visit will leave 1 month after the ambassador with the 9 day visit.

Here's the code that I've been using:

```
solution(X) :- 
    % Instatiate the lists
    ...
    % Generate all possible solutions
    ...
    % Format the variables as solutions table
    X = [[M1, Dm1, Dr1, C1],
         [M2, Dm2, Dr2, C2],
         [M3, Dm3, Dr3, C3],
         [M4, Dm4, Dr4, C4],
         [M5, Dm5, Dr5, C5]],

    ...

    % Rule in question
    % Month1, Month2, Days1, Days2 
    % are all instantiated as integers

    forall((member([Month1, _, Days1, _], X), 
            member([Month2, _, Days2, _], X),
            Days1=3, Days2=9),
            (Y is Month2 + 1, Month1 = Y)).
```

The problem comes when I generate the solutions and the first one is:

```
S = [[5, owens, 10, helsinki], 
     [6, nguyen, 9, kiev], 
     [7, fitzgerald, 2, athens], 
     [8, howell, 6, brussels], 
     [9, vasquez, 3, paris]]
```

The second row and the row list violate the rule and I cant figure out for the life of me what the issue is. It very well could be the logic itself, but I think that I am having trouble grasping how arithmetic is used in prolog.

Is there anything with the logic or the arithmetic that I am obviously not grasping?

Edit:

This is the code relevant to the issue. I had renamed the variables above for clarity and their original names were part of the issue:

```
solution(X) :- 
    % Instatiate the lists 
    % Durations and Months are lists of integers
    diplomats(Diplomats),
    durations(Durations), 
    capitals(Capitals),
    months(Months),

    % Generate all possible solutions
    % (brute force)
    permutation([Dm1, Dm2, Dm3, Dm4, Dm5], Diplomats), 
    permutation([Dr1, Dr2, Dr3, Dr4, Dr5], Durations),
    permutation([C1, C2, C3, C4, C5], Capitals),
    [M1, M2, M3, M4, M5] = Months,

    % Format the variables as solutions table
    X = [[M1, Dm1, Dr1, C1],
         [M2, Dm2, Dr2, C2],
         [M3, Dm3, Dr3, C3],
         [M4, Dm4, Dr4, C4],
         [M5, Dm5, Dr5, C5]],

    %Rule 1
    forall(member([M, Dm, Dr, C], X), 
           rule1(M, Dm, Dr, C)),

    % Rule 2
    forall(member([M, _, Dr, _], X),
           rule2(M, Dr)),

    % ...


    % Rule in question
    % Month1, Month2, Days1, Days2 
    % are all instantiated as integers

    forall((member([M1, _, Dr1, _], X), 
            member([M2, _, Dr2, _], X),
            Dr1=3, Dr2=9),
           (Y is M2 + 1, M1 = Y)).
```

The issue is that I reused the variable names and that caused clashes. I renamed the variables in each *forall(...)* to be unique and it has corrected the problem.

Comment: When I run this, it fails for the proposed solution. The `forall(..)` can be refactored to look more elegant, but as far as I can see is correct.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What did you use to run the code? I'm using the linux command line tool and it's not cooperating apparently.

Comment: I unified `X` with your proposed solution (`S = ...`), and then ran the `forall(...)`, and that returns `false`, perhaps there is a "variable clash" (in the sense that you reuse variables already defined earlier in your program).

Comment: Ah, yep. Haven't been doing this long enough to know variable clash. That is 100% the issue. Thank you so much!!

Comment: you really should include all the relevant code here.